# How can we set firewall rules to allow or deny specific programs?

Tags: users, firewall, group, uid

[This tutorial](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/web-content-filtering-made-easy/) shows how to set up an easy parental control facility, with help of DansGuardian, Privoxy and a few firewall rules. I've tested it and so far, it seems to be working for most part.

There are, however, some things I fail to understand. Namely, in this tutorial we are told to set up, among others, following firewall rules:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m owner --uid-owner privoxy -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 8118 -m owner --uid-owner dansguardian -j ACCEPT
```

Wait... `-m owner --uid-owner dansguardian`, `-m owner --uid-owner privoxy`??

I always thought that uids can be either usernames or groups, which can be assigned to users, and not processes or files? I must've been wrong...

This is even more confusing because `getent group` shows an entry for `dansguardian`, but not for `privoxy`; so I'm not sure what does this `--uid-owner privoxy` refers to, since `privoxy` is neither a user nor group.

Thanks in advance for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always thought that uids can be either usernames or groups

Those *are* user names. It's intended that you run `Privoxy` under a user called `prixovy` and `DansGuardian` under a user called `dansguardian`.

> This is even more confusing because getent group shows an entry for dansguardian, but not for privoxy

Do `cat /etc/passwd` to see the list of users. Most likely, `privoxy` is a user on your system if you installed the `privoxy` package in Debian or Ubuntu. There might not be a corresponding `group` as there is for `dansguardian`.

Comment: Is it possible to declare that a binary should always be run under a certain username? Or does this have to be declared in the source code of this binary?

Comment: @gaazkam Just `chown` the binary to that user and `chmod 0700` it. Or even `chmod 0500` if it has no business modifying itself. Note that it can always `chmod` itself back to `+w` if it really wants to.

Comment: Wait, if I `chown` the binary to a username like `privoxy` and set perms like these, then I won't be able to run this binary unless I'll log in as `privoxy`, right? So how possible Privoxy can run under username `privoxy` even though I'm logged in as e.g. `gaazkam` and not `privoxy`?

Comment: @gaazkam Privoxy is started by the service manager (systemd), which runs as root and can therefore set to any other user before running a command. If you become root with `sudo -i`, you will be able to use `su - username` to become any user (at least, any user that has a working shell configured; systemd doesn't have this limitation as it can bypass the shell).

Answer (score 0):

You can block it based on which ports used by programs like messenger applications. You cant block it based on programs name when you used iptables. Some firewalls can block it based on programs name.